# Active Admin - How to add a 'confirm' pop up when a form is being updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is it possible to add a confirmation type alert to the update action in an active admin form?

What i mean is, when the user clicks `Update` on the form i want an alert to pop up (much like the alert that pops up when `Delete` is clicked) that asks them to confirm whether they are sure...

I have the following in the form:

```
f.actions
```

Seems like this should be a simple thing to do but i can't figure out what it wants?

I now have the following in my **active_admin.js** file:

```
$("#order_submit_action").submit(function(e) {
    alert("Are you sure?");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But it doesn't work?! (no JS errors either)

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of using a submit button to call your alert i think what will be better is to use a simple button tag which will then call your modal, alerting user and containing your submit button

Comment: @Mandeep I've added the code for a subsequent attempt but nothing happens. The `confirm: "Are you sure?"` part seems to break it..

Comment: you can't alert like this. you need to use jquery and make a modal which will have your alert text and submit button

Comment: i'm insisting on making a modal because submit button will probably redirect your page and you want popup also so just to make a proper flow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **app/assets/active_admin.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('form').submit (event)->
    if confirm 'Are you sure?'
      true
    else
      event.preventDefault()
```

Replace `$('form')` by your own matchers, and it should work nicely !

Comment: thanks for the advice @Dimitri. I've decided to go with jQuery but have come across a problem which i've noted in the question..thanks

Comment: This is strange, which version of **activeadmin** do you use?

Comment: Do you have `//= require active_admin/base` in your active_admin.js file?

Comment: ah seems like i deleted that by accident when editing the code, thanks! But annoyingly the code still doesn't work?

Comment: Do you have any javascript error or it's just the confirm popup not showing?

Comment: there aren't any JS errors no. The alert on it's own works so must be this that is not working for some reason `$("#order_submit_action").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: for some reason, `#order_submit_action` is not getting targeted so the code doesn't even begin..any ideas? @Dimitri

Comment: Did you make sure to plug this callback after page has loaded? Try `$(function() {
  return $("#order_submit_action").submit(function(e) {
    return e.preventDefault();
  });
});`, but don't forget that `preventDefault` will avoid your form being actually submitted.

Comment: nothing i try seems to work. Tried what you suggested and nothing...arghhh

Comment: Can you put an `alert('something')` instead of `e.preventDefault()` just to be sure that it's not called?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `.submit()` was not having any effect so i solved with the following:

```
$(function() { 
    $("form input[type=submit] ").on("click", function(){
    var con = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this?");
        if (con == true) {

        }
        else
            return false;           
}); 
});
```

Comment: Still relevant 4 years later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby on Rails

Ruby on Rails allows you to add a confirmation dialog by using a data attribute.

```
<%= f.submit 'Save', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

#### ActiveAdmin

In ActiveAdmin / Formtastic, you can leverage this Rails behavior with `button_html`. No extra JavaScript needed.

```
f.actions do
  f.action :submit, button_html: { 'data-confirm': 'Are you sure?' }
  # Preserve the usual cancel button and its styling.
  f.action :cancel, as: :link, label: 'Cancel', wrapper_html: { class: 'cancel' }
end
```